# How to print a directory tree in the specific way, using Files.newDirectoryStream and recursion?

Tags: java

For example, I have a folder "university". I need to print all folders and files inside "university" in the way as shown below:

```
        university
        ├── file.txt
        ├── floor 1
        │   └── room 102
        │       └── file.txt
        ├── floor 2
        │   ├── left wing
        │   │   ├── kitchen
        │   │   │   └── kitchen.txt
        │   │   └── room 232
        │   └── right wing
        │       └── room 252
        │           ├── file1.txt
        │           └── file2.txt
        └── floor 3
            └── room 374
                └── file.txt
```

I am allowed to use recursion and Files.newDirectoryStream() method, or Files.list() as analogue. I know some solutions of my problem, like binary tree or something like that, but I can use only what I told.

This is what I tried:

```
public class Main {
private static final String UNIVERSITY = "university";
private static final Path UNIVERSITY_FOLDER = Paths.get(UNIVERSITY);
private static final StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    createTree(UNIVERSITY_FOLDER);

}

private static void printTree(Path path) throws IOException {
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
        Iterator<Path> iter = stream.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Path currentFile = iter.next();
            appendSpaces(currentFile);
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                result.append("├── ");
            } else {
                result.append("└── ");
            }
            result.append(currentFile.getFileName());
            result.append(System.lineSeparator());
            if (Files.isDirectory(currentFile)) {
                printTree(currentFile);
            }
        }
    } catch (DirectoryIteratorException ex) {
        throw ex.getCause();
    }

}

private static void createTree(Path path) throws IOException {
    result.append(path.getFileName());
    result.append(System.lineSeparator());
    printTree(path);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}

private static void appendSpaces(Path path) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (path.getNameCount() - 2); i++) {
        result.append("│   ");
    }
}
```

}

My code is working, but it prints something like that:

```
university
├── file.txt
├── floor 1
│   └── room 102
│   │   └── file.txt
├── floor 2
│   ├── left wing
│   │   ├── kitchen
│   │   │   └── kitchen.txt
│   │   └── room 232
│   └── right wing
│   │   └── room 252
│   │   │   ├── file1.txt
│   │   │   └── file2.txt
└── floor 3
│   └── room 374
│   │   └── file.txt
```

I need an additional condition for printing this symbol "│", but maybe I went in completely wrong way.
I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see for the elements in room 252, when you `printSpaces`, you need print 3 'indents', and your code always prints `"|   "` as indent. But what it would need to print for 252 is `"|   "` for the first indent, but `"    "` as second and third.

But then imagine floor 3 had a room 375, then for room 374's entries, you'd have to print `"    "` for the first indent and `"|   "`  for the second indent.

That shows that the code that prints indents, which is currently passed a single number listing how many indents to print, is fundamentally broken. It needs to be passed instead an array or other list-like structure. You don't pass '3', you pass 'true, false, false' or something along these lines instead.

To make matters worse, you currently pass the file name to appendSpaces and write some code to do path depth analysis on that to know how many indents there even are, which is just a non-starter: A given path just **cannot know**, per indent, whether you need to draw the line or just a blank block of spaces.

There are many solutions, but the most commonly employed one is to use a recursion helper. For most recursion algorithms, you want some variables that track information such as 'how many indents' (or in this case, a bunch of flags, one for each indent, to indicate whether to draw the bar or not). For the *first* call (the one users of your code make), these tracker variables make no sense, so you make a helper instead. Thus, instead of:

```
public static void printTree(... params ...) {
   // code that will eventaully call printTree recursively
}
```

you do this instead:

```
public static void printTree(.... params ...) {
    printTree0(param1, param2, param3, new boolean[0]);
}

private static void printTree0(... params ..., boolean[] indents) {
    // code that calls printTree0 recursively
}
```

This is a very common pattern:

- The public method just contains a one-liner that calls a private method, passing all all the arguments in the same order, and in addition some more variables, all at initial values (0, or in this case, an empty boolean array, indicating no indents are needed at the root level).
- The private method (appending a `0` is a somewhat common java idiom to indicate 'this is a helper method') is recursively written, the public one is not.

Your `indents` tracker var contains those flags, of whether to print a bar or not.

Every time you recurse you make a new boolean array, adding the right indent:

```
boolean[] newIndents = Arrays.copyOf(indents, indents.length + 1);
newIndents[indents.length] = true or false (depending on whether you want bars or not).
```

From there I'm sure you can figure it out, as you've almost completed the assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your answer is very detailed and I understood all your comments and tips. With your help I finally completed the task and learnt something new. I did not expect that there would be a detailed, good answer to my question, because it is my first question :D